# JSON_ENCODE can't encode large array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I need help with encoding large array into JSON using PHP's json_encode(). The array is from a local Database. I am using JS to parse JSON. However, the PHP script that handles array to JSON format stops if the dataset is too big. 
(i.e 100,000 Results). I tried to up my memory_limit to -1 and still does not help. Is it possible to encode a big array using PHP's json_encode()?

Please let me know if my question is too confusing.

Thank you all!

Comment: The problem with `JSON_ENCODE` in php is, it tends to add double quotes and escaping sequences which would increase the actual size of the JSON being imported, Why can't you handle this at client side?

Comment: @DavidR JSON format is needed because it will be used by others (theoretically).

Comment: @PaulCrovella Just Blank page. The page just stopped.

Comment: Some code samples may help. How are you passing the JSON between PHP and JS?

Comment: Does it really make sense to return such large results? Wouldn't you be better of using pagination? The client browser probably won't like the size of the dataset either.

Comment: @Fencer04 Hi Fencer04, this is the sample code i used.

sample.php file
`<?php 

$sqlQuery = "SELECT * this_table";
$results = $sql->fetchArray($sqlQuery);
$data = array();
foreach ($results as $rows){
    $data[] = array ("id" => $rows['id'], "name" =>$rows['name']);

}
echo json_encode($data);
?>`

.js/html that handles the JSON

`$.ajax ({
  type: "POST",
  url: "sample.php",
 dataType: "json",
 success: function (data){
   $.each (data, function(i,item){
     $("table").append("<tr><td>data[i].id</td><td>data[i].name</td></tr>);
  })
}
   
});`

Comment: @jcaron Yes agreed, I tried to argue with that but they won't allow me to. It's for a school project. :/

Comment: Edit your question to add the code rather than put it in a comment where it's hardly readable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If each of the rows in your array are successfully encoded by `json_encode`, then take advantage of that fact by only encoding each row and echo'ing out the array structure yourself.

That is

```
$prefix = '';
echo '[';
foreach($rows as $row) {
  echo $prefix, json_encode($row);
  $prefix = ',';
}
echo ']';
```

If the nesting is more complex, then a bit more detailed technique needs to be employed, but this technique saved me when I encountered the problem.

Comment: Fancier way:
$largeJson = '['.implode(',', array_map(function($item) { return json_encode($item); })).']';

 :)

Answer (score 0):

The acceptable answer is this

```
$prefix = ''; 
echo '[';  
foreach($rows as $row) {
 echo $prefix, json_encode($row);  $prefix = ','; 
} 
echo ']';
```

posted above.

However, it is still not guarantee to work if the dataset is too big.

The possible solutions are Limit the Query. Instead of using SELECT *. Just select which rows you need BUT in my case, I have no absolute control of the query. So this solution is not gonna work for me .

Last one is to upgrade our server's memory or even the server itself, to keep up with the continuously growing dataset.

Thanks all for your help!